# React keycloak integration not redirect to login page

Tags: reactjs, keycloak, openid-connect

I am using `@react-keycloak/web` for react app securing using keycloak. But the react loading page has no effect on it. Is there I missed something to setup or what is the issues?
Here is my code...

`keycloak.js`

```
import Keycloak from 'keycloak-js'

const keycloakConfig = {
  url: 'http://localhost:8080/auth',
  realm: 'my_local',
  clientId: 'test_client',
  onLoad: 'check-sso'
}

const keycloak = new Keycloak(keycloakConfig)

export default keycloak
```

My `index.js`

```
import { ReactKeycloakProvider } from '@react-keycloak/web'
import keycloak from './keycloak'

<ReactKeycloakProvider
  authClient={keycloak}
  onEvent={eventLogger}
  onTokens={tokenLogger}
>
<App />
</ReactKeycloakProvider>
```

[image]

Answer (score 12):

I solved this problem by moving the onLoad parameter in the provider.
I had the same problem and found this solution by chance.

```
import Keycloak from 'keycloak-js'

const keycloakConfig = {
  url: 'http://localhost:8080/auth',
  realm: 'my_local',
  clientId: 'test_client',
}

const keycloak = new Keycloak(keycloakConfig)

export default keycloak
```

```
import { ReactKeycloakProvider } from '@react-keycloak/web'
import keycloak from './keycloak'

<ReactKeycloakProvider
  initOptions={{ onLoad: 'login-required' }}
  authClient={keycloak}
  onEvent={eventLogger}
  onTokens={tokenLogger}
>
<App />
</ReactKeycloakProvider>
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to change the config **onLoad** value from **check-sso** to **login-required**. That should make it hit your keycloak login page rather than just checking if already authenticated.

Comment: There will be a "hit" (redirect) to the keycloak page in both cases, only difference is if you are not logged in, "check-sso" redirects you back to the app, but "login-required" forces you to submit the keycloak login form.